# AutoLayout doesn't resize properly

Tags: ios

This is my view's hierarchy
superview
-wrapperview
-- childview
--childview

When I using autolayout, what I want is all subviews will have width equal with superview. But just wrapperview is equal

Example: 
- In portrait: superview = wrapperview = 768 but childviews is 1024
- In landscape: superview = wrapperview = 1024 but childview is 768

Anyone know what's happened there?

Answer (score 0):

If the child view's is pinned to the edges of your super view and it's content is bigger than the superview (which is likely in your case), then it will push the view out if you're using the visual formatting language.

For example, suppose your childView is a UIImageView, and has a image with dimension 1024 x 1024.

If your auto layout is something like:

```
[self.wrapperView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[imageView]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
```

Then your imageView will push the wrapperView out.

What you need to do is use this method of constraints, which is a bit more explicit:

```
[self.wrapperView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.childView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.wrapperView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0]];
```

This tells autolayout, your child view's width should be equal to wrapper view's width, and never greater than (as specified by the NSRelationEqual flag).

Comment: No, nothing is bigger than superview.